# Group by, count the wrong column

Tags: mysql, group-by

Im trying to learn about Group by, but have get stuck.

```
SELECT members.username,COUNT(participants.goals) AS ggoals FROM participants
LEFT JOIN members
ON participants.mid=members.userid
GROUP BY username;
```

It seems to work just fine, but the problem is that it count number of rows in participants instead of numbers of goals from same table.

Comment: Why don't use `SUM()` instead of `COUNT()`?

Comment: Can you provide some sample data and desired output?

Comment: Leonel: Sum did it. Now it works just fine. Thank you!